# Finishing options for naturally looking wood flooring

Tags: wood, surface-preparation, natural-wood, flooring

I have sanded my wood flooring and  I want to put a protecting finish on it.

I want to keep it looking as natural as I can and not shiny.

Any help please

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Define "natural". Everyone has their own idea of what looks natural when it comes to woodwork; what's yours? You can add some pics of the look you're aiming for if necessary.

Comment: @Theresa_Small also: what about clear or "natural" color and/or a standard satin finish do you find undesirable?